# Dynamic SQL query for dynamic input boxes in python flask

Tags: html, mysql, sql, flask

I have a HTML table with 5 columns, with each column having one text box. The number of rows are dynamic. How to formulate update query based on this, where each HTML table row indicates one entry into SQL table. How to write update query for dynamic HTML row values?

Only one submit button at the end of the table is present.

Comment: You don't need a dynamic SQL query, just iterate posted form's columns and invoke inserts/updates on each one.

Comment: is there any example so that I ca easily understand it?